# Из формы в форму C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Цель - передать из основной формы во второстепенную массив со значениями в виде id выделенных строк `datagridview` для последующего использования в запросе, в части `WHERE code in (тут то что передаем)`.

Реализация - в основной форме делаю так:

```
private void test()
{
    int countSelectString = gridShift.SelectedRows.Count;
    GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill = new int[countSelectString];
    for (int i = 0; i < countSelectString; i++)
    {
        GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill[i] = int.Parse(gridShift.SelectedRows[i].Cells["shiftcode"].Value.ToString());
    }  
}
```

`GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill` - глобальная переменная массив `public static int[] edit_shift_waybill { set; get; }`

Проблема в следующем - как мне результат того, что я записал в `GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill`, привести в такой вид: `(100566, 100564, 100378)` - для последующего использования в запросе в `WHERE code in (тут)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну скажем так:

```
var result = "("+ string.Join(", ", GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill) +")";
```

Но мой вам совет, лучше не массив, а `List<int>` использовать. Меньше проблем будет.
Вместо этого:

```
public static int[] edit_shift_waybill { set; get; }
```

Напишите:

```
public static List<int> edit_shift_waybill { set; get; }
```

А в статичном конструкторе своего класса `GlobalVariable` напишите следующее (ну или где угодно, до того как начнете использовать эту переменную:

```
edit_shift_waybill = new List<int>();
```

Иначе у вас программа упадет с ошибкой.

Как добавить в список элемент:

```
 GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill.Add(someIntVariable)
```

До того как нужно сформировать новый список, нужно не забыть очистить предыдущие значения:

```
GlobalVariable.edit_shift_waybill.Clear();
```

Остальное можете сами почитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

В основном он ведет себя так же как и обычный массив. 
Почему лучше использовать его? Массивы фиксированной длинны. И может так получиться, что берете вы пару элементов, потом преобразуете как я сказал и получаете что-то типа `(25949, 5461, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.....0)` или выбранных элементов получится больше чем элементов в массиве и при очередной попытки добавить туда элемент программа грохнется. Со временем вы поймете, что массивы в `.Net` устарели и нужны только в некоторых простых случаях, не более.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример работает! Подскажите про совет, я новичок в C#, возможно у вас есть где то не большой пример?

Comment: Если работает - примите ответ нажав галочку.

Comment: Про совет сейчас напишу в ответе.

Comment: массивы не устарели. Массив - более низкоуровневая конструкция, которая лежит в основе List<T>, Queue<T>, и многих других коллекций, не основанных на связных списках или деревьях. Просто List<T> позволяет не думать о своевременном увеличении массива и прочих низкоуровневых штуках, там где это не критично для производительности и не важно для алгоритма и предоставляет дополнительные рюшечки программисту. Более того, в ряде случаев используются только базовые массивы, особенно там, где производительность критична, не забывайте, что автоматическое увеличение List<T> не бесплатное.

Comment: Да вы правы, я в общем-то не совсем корректно выразился. Но по сути, нужда в массивах весьма невелика.

Comment: величина нужды зависит от решаемой задачи. Если количество элементов постоянно - правильнее завести массив а не лист и плодить лишний memory-трафик на ресайзах. К тому же массивы не хуже LIst реализуют ICollection и делать с ними можно практически все тоже самое.

Comment: Всё так, где количество элементов фиксировано - массивы сам бог велел, но в большинстве случаев выигрыш производительности несущественен, по крайней мере я не сталкивался с такими случаями где это было критично, ну с битмапами работал в `unsafe` но там, все равно, дженерики недоступны. В остальных случаях List работает на отлично. Так что думаю спор как-то, во-первых, немножечко оффтоповый, во-вторых, не стоит свеч.

Comment: так почему этот самый int[] не передать в качестве аргумента конструктора формы, ведь наверняка для отображения формы используете что то вроде `var form = new Form2(); form.Show();`просто у Form2 объявить конструктор Form2(int[] arr), а после уже обрабатывать этот массив в коде формы потребителя? П.с. как по мне глобальные переменные зло...

Comment: kimmaman2, да, не то чтоб зло, но костыль изрядный. Но вопрос то был конкретный, на него и ответил =)

Comment: @Сергей я не со зла, просто на работе по рукам за такое бьют (CR и возврат на доработку), хотел просто предостеречь человека)

Comment: Угу. У него вопрос не очень хорошо оформлен, в заголовке одно, в вопросе несколько иное. Ну пусть так хоть сделает, шишки набьет. Новичку сложно в таком шквале ньюансов разобраться сразу.